# getting a primitive from a struct based on it index

Tags: c, struct

Ive got the following

```
typedef struct{

GLfloat x;

GLfloat y;

GLfloat z;


}Vertex3D;
```

and I want to use a for loop. is it possible to specify which primitive you want from a struct based on its index. e.g if I wanted using the number 0 for x 1 for y and 2 for z like an array?

Thanks for all your responses. I think I will use arrays instead. Was hoping to avoid it but ow well. GC

Comment: Why not `struct { float x[3]; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not legally.  The structure's elements might be aligned in memory, but I highly recommend not doing it this way, it could cause many headaches later, especially if you find your struct needs additional members later.

Try instead:

```
typedef struct
{
    GLfloat c[3];
}Vertex3D;
```

and

```
#define VERTEX_X 0
#define VERTEX_Y 1
#define VERTEX_Z 2
```

then access with:

```
Vertex3D v;
v.c[VERTEX_X] = 5.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
((GLfloat *)&Vertex3D)[i];
```

but that's just ugly.

Edit: As an answer below points out, this technically might not even work. it is possible (though improbable for this particular situation) that the elements would be padded and not contiguous in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That would work but as you say ugly. Is there no better way?

Comment: @geminiCoder Well I don't think there's any built-in functionality designed to do exactly what you want here. Some of the other suggestions below have other decent solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, not cleanly. You could do

```
Vertex3D v;
float *pv = (float*)&v;
/* use pv[0],pv[1],pv[2] */
```

Technically, it's undefined behavior, but *in this particular case*, I wouldn't expect problems on any wide-spread compiler/OS/CPU combination.

Comment: Most compilers support nonstandard directives which provide explicit control over data member alignment in structs and classes.  That said, they are not always portable (since they are nonstandard) and they make the design of your program very difficult to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the way that the struct is stored in memory, but I would advise against it. Because all of the elements are located right next to each other in memory, you could treat it as an array, which is technically an undefined behavior, but as long as everything in your struct is the same type, it shouldn't cause any issues (because then it's basically an array).

Here's a test program that I made to prove this

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Point;

int main() {

    Point test = {1, 2, 3};

    printf("x: %d\ty: %d\tz: %d\n", test.x, test.y, test.z);

    int *ptest = (int *) &test;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d\n", ptest[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

works as expected